# Electron app with zerorpc on armv7l crashes

Tags: python-3.x, electron

I am trying to build an app for armv7l architecture. Using electron-packager, I am able to build it. But while running it, it crashes with segmentation fault on startup. Can anyone help to fix this?

Or, can anyone suggest alternative to zerorpc, fo communicating between python code and electron module?

Comment: did you find any solution to this or alternative for zerorpc?

Comment: No. I was not able to find the solution to above problem. So, I gave up on electron and started using frameworks like flask and eel.